# Swap инициализированного и неинициализированного итераторов

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, swap

Следующий код в Visual Studio 2010 падает на строке

```
std::swap(it, ms.it);
```

с сообщением

> Необработанное исключение в "0x00d521a4" в "test.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000000".

Но он пажает только если ровно в один (не важно, какой именно) из сетов была сделана вставка. Если не сделана ни в один, либо сделана в оба, то всё отрабатывает без проблем.

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct myset
{
  set <int> s;
  set <int> :: iterator it;

  void insert(int x)
  {
    s.insert(x);
    it = s.begin();
  }

  void swap(myset &ms)
  {
    s.swap(ms.s);
    std::swap(it, ms.it); // Необработанное исключение в "0x00d521a4" в "test.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000000".
  }
};

int main()
{
  myset a, b;

  b.insert(1); // !!!

  a.swap(b); // Один пустой, а другой - нет

  return 0;
}
```

Этот же код на ideone не падает: https://ideone.com/5l8ku7.

В чём проблема?

Comment: VC++ 2017 не падает. Остается предположить ошибку в 2010? **update** У меня не падает и на 2010...

Comment: @Harry, у меня даже пример упрстить не выходит - без класса не падает. Но паает непосредственно на вызове swap, не деструктор. Может быть и в VS2010 дело, не знаю.

Comment: а под дебагом или под релизом падает?

Comment: @pavel, в дебаге. Но тот код, который я упрощал, падал в обоих, вроде.

Comment: интересно, что в msdn сказано, что начиная с 2013 студии итераторы не портятся после insert, А вот о версии 2010-2012 ничего не написано. Поэтому....

Comment: а вы попробуйте  инициализировать it еще и в конструкторе ...

Comment: @KoVadim, после insert ничего не портится - это 100%. Валится именно при пустом сете, даже при свопе руками через промежуточную переменную.

Comment: Я тут подумал, а разве можно обменивать итераторы? Нужно же обменивать значения.

Comment: @KoVadim, зачем значения? Мне итераторы нужны. Класс - в нёсм хранится сет и итератор на некоторый элемент этого сета. Я свопаю сеты и итераторы. Всё как задумано.